# Measure wall clock time before and after a function

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, time

I am measuring wall time through the use of clock_gettime() found in . It works perfectly fine when i use it in main() but not the way i am attempting to use it.

I am familiarizing myself with the linux scheduler and i am measuring performance on different parts.
I want to be able to measure **Waiting time** which is defined by "the total time a thread spends in the ready queue" (how long until it starts executing the function).

Easily enough i can measure this by setting a clock_gettime() before the thread function and another right inside the function. However the problem i am having is that the time inside the thread function is lower than the one outside, giving us a negative time.

I am running this on my windows pc through ubuntu.

what could the problem be?

code:

```
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&data.before);
    thread_array[i-1] = data;
    if(pthread_create(&tids[i],&attr,workLoad,(void*) &data) != 0){
                perror("Could not create thread");
                return 1;
            }
        }

    for(int i = 1;i < threadAmount; i++){
            if(pthread_join(tids[i],NULL)!= 0){
                perror("Thread could not wait");
                return 1;
            }
        }
```

and here is my threadfunc:

```
void *workLoad(void *args) 
{   
    threadData* data = (threadData*) args;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&data->after);
    int loopAmount = data->loopAmount;
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < loopAmount; i++){
        counter++;
    }
    return NULL; 
}
```

result of time intervall

[image]

Comment: Try using CLOCK_MONOTONIC

Comment: it brings out the same result, negative time @Wazzaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following code:

```
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&data.before);
thread_array[i-1] = data;
if(pthread_create(&tids[i],&attr,workLoad,(void*) &data) != 0){
```

`data` seems to be a local variable whose address you pass to the thread. You also copy this variable into `thread_array[i-1]`. If you then do `thread_array[i-1].after - thread_array[i-1].before` then that means that the thread updates a wrong variable. You need to pass `&thread_array[i-1]` to that thread, e.g.:

```
if(pthread_create(&tids[i],&attr,workLoad,(void*)&thread_array[i-1]) != 0){
```